# Meteor.call doesn’t work on android App

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, mobile

I created a simple app using Meteor 1.3, which has only one method. It works like that: When a button is clicked, the method is invoked - it calculates a specific value and returns the result.

The app works perfectly on the localhost server, but when I launch it on my device with "meteor run android-device", it cannot access the method (simply opens the app, but nothing happens when I press a button.

Do you know how I could resolve this?

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

import './main.html';

Template.check.onCreated(function checkOnCreated() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict();
});

Template.check.events({
   'click .checkit'(event, instance) {

      Meteor.call('code.check', function(error, result){
       if(error){
         console.log('Error from the client side!');
       } else {
         instance.state.set('fett', result.titles[0]);
       }
      });
    },

 });

Template.check.helpers({

  fett() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    if (instance.state.get('fett')) {
      return instance.state.get('fett');
    } else {
        return 'Value still not known...'
    }
   },
 });
```

Comment: Where did you put the file containing the Meteor methods (in the client/server folder) ?

Comment: The methods are put in "imports/api/tasks.js file. They are imported with "import '../imports/api/tasks.js';" in "server/main.js" file. The app works in the web, but on on the mobile!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your smartphone's WiFi is turned on and it connected to the same WiFi network as you computer where meteor app is running. Then everything should work fine.

Also, I recommend to use chrome://inspect feature (more info [here](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/)) in order to debug your app on Android. Then, you will be able quickly investigate any problems with mobile app.

Comment: Also take into consideration: if you are connected to a VPN, or have a firewall on your computer.